# Future adjustment of minimum ADA to be sent?

Tags: ada

I am wondering about the minimum amount of ADA to be sent with a transaction (and/or has to be held by a wallet alongside a CNFT): Right now its 1,379something, but there surely has to be a plan how and when to lower this amount as ADA vs USD reaches higher levels?

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Micro-transactions*](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/639/what-are-the-long-term-micro-transaction-plans-for-cardano) with [*low fees*](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/815/why-are-cardano-transaction-fees-so-high/4009#4009) will become possible when Hydra is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question but could be useful for you and others.

Since `cardano-cli` 1.31, there is a new command to calculate the minimum required ADA for a transaction output:

- `cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-required-utxo`

```
Usage: cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-required-utxo 
            [ --byron-era
            | --shelley-era
            | --allegra-era
            | --mary-era
            | --alonzo-era
            ]
            (--genesis FILE | --protocol-params-file FILE)
            --tx-out ADDRESS VALUE
            [ --tx-out-datum-hash HASH
            | --tx-out-datum-hash-file FILE
            | --tx-out-datum-hash-value JSON VALUE
            | --tx-out-datum-embed-file FILE
            | --tx-out-datum-embed-value JSON VALUE
            ]

  Calculate the minimum required UTxO for a transaction output.
```